# Love2D no carga el main.lua

Tags: lua, love2d

Estoy a la vez que probando a programar en Lua también en Love2D y desconozco el echo a pesar de que por lo que **entiendo tengo la librería completamente configurada atreves de la consola no me arranca el archivo main.lua y e probado muchas maneras diferentes** localizaciones de archivo y **comprobé que no sea un problema de permisos**, **si hay una manera de arrancar el archivo con Love2D pero con el editor de Visual Code** gracias a una extensión que uso con el para programar pero nada más.

Para dejarlo mas claro dejare el mensaje que lanza la ventaba de Love2D:

> Error
>
> [love "boot.lua"]:323: Cannot load game at path '[Link removido
> personalmente]/main.lua'. Make sure a folder exists at the specified
> path.
>
> Traceback
>
> [love "callbacks.lua"]:228: in function 'handler' [C]: in function
> 'error' [C]: in function 'xpcall' [C]: in function 'xpcall'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estuve tratando de resolver el problema y había dos, **en variables de entorno se tenia que poner el link del lugar donde se localiza Love2D en variables del usuario en vez de variable de sistema**, lo cual hice debido a la costumbre al instalar Lua y Luarocks. El segundo problema era que **Love2D no arranca con el archivo de main.lua, Love2D arranca con la carpeta en la cual este se encuentra**.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).